# How can i remove ImageMagick 7 completely from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, imagemagick

I have to remove ImageMagick 7 completely from my system. I have a rails app which requires ImageMagick 6. I have tried the following commands to remove but nothing works.

```
'sudo apt remove --purge imagemagick'
'sudo make uninstall'
```

When i check my ImageMagick version with convert --version command it still gives this

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-39 Q16 x86_64 2019-04-10 
https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg 
lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

How can i remove it and install ImageMagick 6?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just remove it.

There is a page https://packages.ubuntu.com where you can search for packages and files. Using this page one can find out that on Ubuntu 18.04 `/usr/bin/convert` is provided by the package [graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat (1.3.28-2)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat). To remove `convert` you have to remove this package. Now the hard part begins.

This package was (probably) installed because something else you installed asked for it. This other piece of software depends on it. As long as you have that other piece of software installed, your OS will keep re-installing `graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`.

You are probably better of in wrapping your ruby app so that calls to `convert` do not end up with the version installed by your OS but with  a custom imagemagick 6 installation.

According to packages.ubuntu.com, Bionic (a.k.a. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) ships with Imagemagick version 6, see

- [Package imagemagick in bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/graphics/imagemagick)
- [Package imagemagick in bionic-updates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/imagemagick)
- and more specifically the vanilla Imagemagick sources referenced on these pages (imagemagick_6.9.7.4+dfsg.orig.tar.xz)
- also not that even [cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/imagemagick) and [disco](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/graphicsmagick) are on Imagemagick version 6

I think it is rather odd that your Graphicsmagick would report as Imagemagick. You first need to find out how you installed Imagemagick, then you can ask how to reverse that particular process.